# Не могу поднять jSSC-классы <Win10 {JDK 14.0.2}> Код_Ошибки:0xc0000005

Tags: java, windows, arduino, serial, jssc

Делаю проект на JDK 14.0.2 для Arduino nano (CH340), для считывания сериал данных с Микро-Контроллера , и в дальнейшем преобразования их в движение курсором (или в подобные биндинги).

P.s. беру данные с модуля gy-521(MPU-6050);
P.p.s. пишу именно на StackOverflow , так как проблема с Java;

Код:

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortEvent;
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener;
import jssc.SerialPortException;
 
public class Main {
 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * Передаём в конструктор имя порта
     */
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
    try {
      /*
       * Открываем порт
       */
      serialPort.openPort();
      /*
       * Выставляем параметры
       */
      serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
          SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
          SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
          SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

      int mask = SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR;
      /*
       * Выставляем подготовленную маску
       */
      serialPort.setEventsMask(mask);

      serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader(serialPort));
    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 
  static class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
 
    private SerialPort serialPort;
 
    public SerialPortReader(SerialPort serialPort) {
      this.serialPort = serialPort;
    }
 
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

      if (event.isRXCHAR()) {
        if (event.getEventValue() > 0) {
          try {
            String buffer = serialPort.readString();
            System.out.println(buffer);
          } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      } else if (event.isCTS()) {

        if (event.getEventValue() == 1) {
          System.out.println("CTS - ON");
        } else {
          System.out.println("CTS - OFF");
        }
      } else if (event.isDSR()) {
        if (event.getEventValue() == 1) {
          System.out.println("DSR - ON");
        } else {
          System.out.println("DSR - OFF");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
**#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007110b5db, pid=8368, tid=8312
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (14.0.2+12) (build 14.0.2+12-46)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\vasili\eclipse-workspace\SpecularVR-SITD\hs_err_pid8368.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#**
```

Comment: Комрад, ну первая же ссылка в гугле в ведёт на тот же SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482406/fatal-error-attempting-to-write-to-com-port-using-jssc-exception-access-violati

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но создав новый пустой maven проект и добавим зависимости из https://github.com/akuhtz/spsw я получил много ошибок типа "Dependency 'de.ibapl.spsw:de.ibapl.spsw.api:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT' not found". Т.е. проект заброшен. Остальные форки не пробиваются в гугле, и не имеют значения, т.к. без поддержки.

Comment: Я на страничке https://search.maven.org/search?q=jssc перепробовал все вариант по отдельности, в лучшем случае при удачной сборке получаю ошибку "java: error: release version 5 not supported".

Comment: @zolt  и другие ребята - не могли бы вы  подсказать - как быть дальше? Застрял мой проект на ардуино. Т.е. я его подключаю к компу и с помощью джавы пытаюсь что-нибудь сделать.

Comment: Смелое заявление про заброшенность проекта) Последние артефакты в мавене датированы 2019 годом. Это для Java, поверьте, свежак. Версии 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT и правда нет в maven central, но есть версия 2.1.0, попробуйте её.

Comment: @zolt Так и сделал. Пишет "java: error: release version 5 not supported". Можете подсказать, в чём проблема? Когда руками добавляли джарник, другая ошибка была в рантайме.

Comment: Спасибо @zolt , проблема решилась тем, что я все таки импортировал либу com.fazecast.jSerialComm!